# firebreath chrome extension: form saver

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, npapi, firebreath

I have coded a browser helper object in C# for IE, and would like to wrap up that code to implement a chrome/firefox extension. My research led me to [Firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org/). I am now loading a content_script file which will fire an onSubmit event and send a message to backgound.htm,js files which handles my firebreath plugin. However, sure enough, m_host now points to the background htm file rather than the original website (from which the user pressed submit button). I tried replacing the html code form the native plugin, but it is not working..

test setup:

content_script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
alert(document.forms.length);
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
    document.forms[i].addEventListener("submit", function () {
        var documentHTML = "<html>" + document.documentElement.innerHTML + "</html>";
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ inputElement: documentHTML }, function (response) {        }); }); } });
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
     document.getElementById('plugin0').sethtml(request.inputElement); });
```

firebreath code:

```
void coolnewtestpluginAPI::setInnerHTML(const FB::variant& innerHTML)
{
    m_host->getDOMDocument()->setInnerHTML(innerHTML.convert_cast<std::string>());
}
```

The native plugin is being called, and I can debug through it. "setInnerHTML()" returns successfully without any errors, but the html code is not being updated, and refers to the original background.htm file. Any ideas?

PS: I'm not that fluent in javascript, so I'd rather offload as much as possible to c# / c++

Comment: In case you're not aware, Chrome plans to remove NPAPI support by the end of the year, so this Chrome extension has a very limited lifespan.

Comment: would using chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage or chrome.runtime.connectNative be a better option then? I would then probably send individual input elements to the native code from which I'll load my c# library..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to put an NPAPI/FireBreath plugin into the actual page is to inject the object tag into that page using javascript from the extension. Otherwise the plugin will know nothing about that page.